# Partitions in a generating function $(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)...(1-x^{1000})$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, generating-functions

I was trying to find the coefficient of each $x^n$ in the expression

> $$(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)...(1-x^{1000})$$
>   for $n=1,2,3,4...30$

The answer seems to be equivalent to finding $P_{even}$-$P_{odd}$ where

- $P_{even}$ is the number of partitions of $n$ into an even number of distinct parts and
- $P_{odd}$ is the number of ways of partitioning $n$ into an odd number of distinct parts.

This seems complicated. Do not tell me the answer but tell me if there is an easier method to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is the [Euler's pentagonal theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem)

There is an interesting [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEWj93XjON0&t=32m32s) about how Euler solved the problem of the partitions, linked the particular part but I recommend the entire video.

Added:

$\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1-x^i) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i,$

$a_i := \begin{cases}1 & \mbox{ if } i = \frac{1}{2}(3k^2 \pm k) \mbox{ and } k \mbox{ is even}\\
             -1 & \mbox{ if } i = \frac{1}{2}(3k^2 \pm k) \mbox{ and } k \mbox{ is odd }\\
             0 & \mbox{ otherwise }\end{cases}$

$P_{even}-P_{odd}=\sum_{i \mathrm{\ even}} p(n{-}g_i)-\sum_{i \mathrm{\ odd}} p(n{-}g_i)=\sum_{i=0}^n p(n{-}i) a_i=0\ $ ($g_k$ the k<sup>th</sup> generalized pentagonal number)

Comment: As amazing as that video was, I cannot see how to solve this problem using $D(n)=O(n)$ What I need is a formula for $P_{even}-P_{odd}$ where $P_{odd}+P_{even}=D(n)$

Comment: The video was more of an extra but it actually helps because $0=D(n)-O(n)=P_{even}-P_{odd}=\sum_{i \mathrm{\ even}} p(n{-}g_i)-\sum_{i \mathrm{\ odd}} p(n{-}g_i)=\sum_{i=0}^n p(n{-}i) a_i\ $, from there you get that $a_i=1,-1,0\ (\text{ when } i =\frac{1}{2}(3k^2 \pm k)(\text{with k even,odd or no k respectively})$, and by Euler's pentagonal theorem $\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1-x^i) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i\ $, this appears with more detail in the subsection #partition recurrence# of the link, you didn't want the answer so I was sure if put this at first but now I have added it, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let
$$f(x)=(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)...(1-x^{1000})$$
then the coefficient of $x^n$ is $\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ and for this purpose consider $\ln f(x)$ and find a formula for $n$-th derivative.

Comment: I still have to work on it- I am not really good at calculus, but can see how your method might work. However, would this approach actually reveal a fact about the partitions?

Comment: It's not necessary to accept this one :), you should wait for people's answers. I edit the question.